# Select specific localization of Wicket message in HTML

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-8

*Is it possible to force the language of a Wicket message in HTML?*

I have a few wicket pages and generic components that are used both when the user's locale is known and when it is not known. When the locale is not known, I am required to show messages in two official languages (english and german in this example). For now I have made language specific pages for the two languages and a default page for the "unknown" case:

```
MyComponent.html
MyComponent_en.hmtl
MyComponent_de.html
```

The "unknown" page (MyComponent.html) contains message-elements for both languages. At the moment, one of the laguages is the default one and for the common components I have had to duplicate the messages in other languages by appending the language code to the message key:

MyComponent.html:

```
<span lang="en"><wicket:message key="myMessageKey"/></span>
<span lang="de"><wicket:message key="myMessageKey.de"/></span>
```

wicket_package.properties:

```
myMessageKey=My hovercraft is full of eels
myMessageKey.de=Mein Luftkissenfahrzeug ist voller Aale
```

wicket_package_de.properties:

```
myMessageKey=Mein Luftkissenfahrzeug ist voller Aale
```

**Clearly this duplication of localizations is insanity.** Is there a way where I could force the language of the wicket:message in the HTML and save myself from duplicating the localizations? What I am looking for is something like <wicket:message key="myMessageKey" lang="de"/> or anything similar.

One option seems to be making my own `WicketMessageResolver` but I'd rather not do that work if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in current Wicket (9.8.0).

I'd also be hesitant to implement something like `WicketMessageResolver`!
But it would be quite simple to implement with non-auto component (auto-components are all created from markup - `<wicket:xyz>`), i.e. with a custom `Panel` that has two `Label`s which models use `Localizer.get()` to get the localized values.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortuntely I also found a second use case that requires singular messages in a third language on pages where language is known. So creating a copy of WicketMessageResolver and adding the lang attribute was only about a 30 minute job...